# Looking for open-source solution to show map with massive objects(3x3 polygon) on a web site

Tags: google-maps, open-source-gis, spatial-database, google-fusion-tables

I don't have much experiance in GIS systems.

I am developing a web site which need to show a map with 3m x 3m rectangles for a radius of about 400 meters.(about 58,000 polygons for one location)
I need to be able to support about 10,000 locations
Overoll 580000000 objects...

So far I'be been using google maps with javescript V3 to show limited information.
I've examined fusion-table solutions but the abount of data allowed to upload is too small.
I've tested GmapCreator - but if I use csv files - it's about 5.5GB of information and I don't think It will be able to support this amount of data.

The creating of an image tiles file - looks to me like the right directions - but I need to be able to create the image on the fly per demand  and put it over the google map as an layout.(remmeber it should be on a web site)

Can anyone suggest which tools I can use.
My comfort zone is .Net c#.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a database to store all that data - postgres with postgis would be a ideal choice - if you know php/.net you can easily call data from the webserver with postgis on. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPek0qhUuuY

Answer (score 2):

For this many features, you will want to render them into raster tiles.  My recommendation would be to evaluate products that serve up Web maps like MapServer, GeoServer, Mapnick, etc.  MapServer has C# bindings, but you could likely just use the standard WMS or CGI interface.

Depending on your specific use case, you could look at caching with something like mapcache, tilecache, tilestasche, etc.

The trick for this many features will be to pre-compute as much as possible.  Create simplified 'vector overviews' if possible, create spatial indexes.